# SVN+SSH wont connect to remote repository

Tags: svn, ssh

I'm using Putty to connect to my server once I'm connected I can pretty much do whatever i need to do... so, I have a folder called pj so I enter it

> cd /home/user/pj/

Then I need to "put" in that folder a repository that is in another server, so I do this:

> svn co svn+ssh://user@foo.com/branch/pj

it will ask me for a password so I type it, but it doesn't work... BUT! if I access to that server using TortoiseSVN using the same credentials I get a connection!

> svn --username user co snv://foo.com/branch/pj
>   svn co svn://foo.com/branch/pj

with that all i get is a timeout... I don't know what else to do I have configure the Putty to not timeout, keep a live... but is no use... what else can I do?... 
I was thinking to download the repository to my HDD then upload it to my server... I don't know what else to do...

Comment: When using `svn+ssh` you are hitting the raw filesystem as opposed to using `svn` or `http` where url is not necessarily reflective of its location on the filesystem... so the path after the domain needs to be the absolute path on the filesystem. For example is your repository is on that server at: `/var/repositories/someprojectname` then you need to use `svn+ssh://user@foo.com/var/repositories/someprojectname/branches/pj`

Comment: This is not related to PuTTY. PuTTY is a just a Windows SSH client that you use to connect to a remote server, where you run the `svn`.